# Get posts belonging to three categories

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to get posts that match three categories.
For example: if I have three categories, named 1, 2, 3, I want to grab the posts that belong to 1 AND 2 AND 3, and only that posts.
I found a way to make it with two categores:

```
$args = array(

        'category__and' => array(5739,50),
        'posts_per_page' => 10, 
        'orderby' => 'date'
);
```

But not three.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want post belong to this all three categories or post that might belong to any of this category?? (is it necessary for a post to belong all these three categories?)

Comment: posts belong to all three categories..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to **show posts from several categories**

Then you can display it using following code :

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => '2,6,17,38' ) );
```

If you want to **show posts from several categories with AND condition**

Then you can do it using following code:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'category__and' => array( 2, 6 ) ) );
```

If you want to **show posts from several categories with OR condition**

Then you can do it using following code:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'category__in' => array( 2, 6 ) ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use WP_Query for getting posts from multiple categories like:

```
query_posts( array( 'category__and' => array(34,26,29), 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC' ) );
```

Here is the helping link:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters